# How can I type Russian characters with accents in KDE?

Tags: ударение, информатика, typography

I asked this question [in the *Unix & Linux* community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574241/how-can-i-type-russian-characters-with-accents-in-kde), where I think it is on-topic but nobody who knows noticed (and answered) it, so I am repeating it here, although I fear it may be off-topic, but at least someone who knows will probably notice!

> I use KDE and have enabled the Russian keyboard layout. This works fine except that I see no opportunity to add accents to vowels. Is this in fact possible? I wish to use them in applications such as Kate (which uses Unicode/UTF-8 for my document), to mark accented syllables to aid my pronunciation. The help for System Settings - Keyboard talks about levels of keys, but does not say what that means.
>
> I would have expected there to be a dead key for the accent, but cannot find one. If necessary I would be prepared to edit configuration files, but it seems to me unlikely that that would be necessary.
>
> I have my keyboard model set to generic 101-key PC,and my keyboard is a Dell model SK-8115, attached via USB to an Acer laptop. My Linux is Open Suse Leap 15.0 with the latest updates.

That said, I see that the question: “[Does anyone know of a simpler way to add accents to Cyrillic vowels than what is typically found online?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14187/does-anyone-know-of-a-simpler-way-to-add-accents-to-cyrillic-vowels-than-what-is)” is regarded as on-topic and is very close to what I ask, except that is is for MS Windows rather than Linux. I shall post this now, and then see if I can solve my problem with an approach similar to that in the answers to that question.

Comment: Copy from the character map to get a combining accent: а +  ́ = а́, so that seems to produce the desired image, but it is two characters rather than one. Also, I would much rather use a key combination than copy-paste.

Comment: Looked at [Ilya Birman's typography layout](http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/), but it seems to be only for Apple or MS Windows (and my Russian is not yet good enough to understand much of what it says). The Windows version uses a DLL, so I suspect that means it does not work except, possibly, in Wine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about Russian language

Comment: @snabunc: Why is it off-topic if the linked question (the same for Windows) was considered on-topic? (And attracted several useful answers!)

Comment: Hi! You asking a very valid question an honest answer to which is that question is also off-topic, we've just missed it, so I converted it to wiki. The most relevant place I can imagine asking this is Language Learners.